# How to get auto_increment composite key updated after save

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using hibernate with @Embeddable for composite keys.
I have 2 classes for a test:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "da_form_view")
@Data
public class FormView {
  @EmbeddedId
  FormViewPk formViewPk;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class FormViewPk implements Serializable {

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = " int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "curtime", columnDefinition = " int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'")
  private Integer curtime;
}
```

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface FormViewRepository extends JpaRepository<FormView, FormViewPk> {
}
```

When I do a FormViewRepository, save or saveAndFlush, I don't get the FormViewPk.id updated with the value that has been inserted in the DB, it returns a null for that value.
In this case the data base is H2 with autocommit, and I need both keys because that table is using partitions (I can't use only the GeneratedValue as unique key).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation this is not possible.

> When using composite identifiers, the underlying identifier properties
> must be manually assigned by the user.
>
> Automatically generated properties are not supported to be used to
> generate the value of an underlying property that makes the composite
> identifier.
>
> Therefore, you cannot use any of the automatic property generator
> described by the generated properties section like @Generated,
> @CreationTimestamp or @ValueGenerationType or database-generated
> values.

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-generated